# generate ‘Allure Report’ for protractor using jenkins - error "‘Allure Report’ aborted due to exception: java.io.IOException:"

Tags: jenkins, protractor, allure

Unpacking https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/maven-repo1/io/qameta/allure/allure-commandline/2.13.0/allure-commandline-2.13.0.zip to C:\Users\user1G.jenkins\tools\ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation\allure on Jenkins
ERROR: Step ‘Allure Report’ aborted due to exception: 
java.io.IOException: Failed to rename C:\Users\user1G.jenkins\tools\ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation\allure\allure-2.13.0 to C:\Users\user1G.jenkins\tools\ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation\allure\allure-2.13.0.__rename

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this!

java.io.IOException may be its jdk related and Allure requires JDK version 8 or higher.
 Do install jdk version and update JAVA_HOME system variable correctly. Try again !

If still not work put the json-lib jar in JAVA_HOME/lib. I got the jar from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonlib24jdk15jar.htm